# Site statistics for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, statistics

The [Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) has been interesting when it shows up in Hot Network Questions. Some have been really funny and others helpful! If you go to the main site, you will see the site stats on the right side:

[image: Site statistics]

It seems as if this is only view-able in *this* format for beta sites.

Is there a way to view this high-level information for Stack Overflow without querying from [the data explorer?](https://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Like: https://stackexchange.com/sites ?

Comment: I still feel that whole site should be closed as primarily opinion based ...

Comment: Hmm, 100% can't be hard, everybody does it.

Comment: @rene lol. Workplace SE site too, not 100%. But almost

Comment: Interpersonal Skills SE = "How do I know if he/she likes me?"

Comment: @Bergi, Please refer to the masterfully drawn freehand circle in the "wow" text. Flagging comment as not enough research effort before posting..

Comment: Esperanto, workplace, Russian, IPS, WorldBuilding, HomeBrewing, German, Parenting, Writing, RPG and Lifehacks all have 100% (almost seems like the more technical the lower the answered Percent)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can see this information for all sites, including graduated sites, on [stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

As it stands, Stack Overflow's statistics are as follows:

> - 16m questions
> - 24m answers
> - 71% answered
> - 8.6m users
> - 11m visits/day

(you can hover over these on the linked page to get the exact values).

The Stack Exchange sites list also allows you to sort all of the sites in various ways, so you can compare Stack Overflow to any other site (if that's what you want to do!).

As far as I'm aware, the info box isn't available anywhere on Stack Overflow directly, though (as the beta info box is mainly there to help beta communities focus on growing and monitor their site's health).

Comment: I did know about `/sites`. But couldn't find the `X visits/day` metric on there. Thank you!

Comment: @MattR I only saw that metric when I changed the "view mode" to list view in stead of grid mode at the top right corner.